# How to split a string with two different delimiters

Tags: c++, string, vector, split, substring

I would like to store data in an object array but I don't know how to split my string.

The result I would like to see is:

```
tab[0].username = "user1"
tab[0].ip = "192.168.0.1"
tab[1].username = "user2"
tab[1].ip = "192.168.0.2"
tab[2].username = "user3"
tab[2].ip = "192.168.0.3"
```

Here's how my string looks:

```
user1:192.168.0.1|user2:192.168.0.2|user3:192.168.0.3
```

The code I currently have, which only allows you to split without managing the pipe :

```
void addInTab(std::vector<std::string> vec, client *tab, int total_user)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if (i == 0)
            tab[total_user].username = vec[i];
        if (i == 1)
            tab[total_user].ip = vec[i];
    }
}

void split(std::string str, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string::size_type tmp = str.find(delim);

    while(tmp != std::string::npos) {
        vec.push_back(str.substr(0, tmp));
        str = str.substr(tmp + 1);
        tmp = str.find(delim);
    }
    vec.push_back(str);
    addInTab(vec);
}
```

thank advance

Comment: Have you tried using a regex?

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve], as your example can't be compiled. 2) If you need to search for multiple delimiters, why aren't you using [`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)?

Comment: have you considered using find_if instead of find? that would allow you to use your own match checking function and have multiple characters checked

Comment: I'd vote for de-duplication: this question is more specific (much better illustrates the actual problem) whereas the targeted question is *too broad* and not worth the up-votes it attracted.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a more generalized version of the `split` function, that returns the vector instead of calling some special function.

Then you can call it first to split on the pipe character, and in a loop call it *again* to split each sub-string.

Something like this

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str, char delim);

// ...

for (auto pair : split(original_input_with_pipes, '|'))
{
    // Here pair is a string containing values like "user1:192.168.0.1" etc.

    auto values = split(pair, ':');  // Split each pair

    // Now values[0] should be e.g. "user1"
    // and values[1] should be "192.168.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **split twice**, first with `|`, second (on each of the results) with `:` as the delimiter. Here is a quite efficient and compact split function

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& text, const char separator)
{
    std::vector<std::string> items;
    std::istringstream f(text);
    std::string s;
    while (getline(f, s, separator)) {
        items.push_back(s);
    }
    return items;
}
```

If you are **sure** about the fact that the **delimiters alternate**, you can build a specialized function, by swapping the delimiters, here a short [demo](https://rextester.com/DEM94680):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "user1:192.168.0.1|user2:192.168.0.2|user3:192.168.0.3";
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > pairs;
    std::istringstream f(text);
    std::string name, ip;
    while (getline(f, name, ':')) {
        if (getline(f, ip, '|')) {
            pairs.push_back(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(name, ip));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (auto pair: pairs) {
        std::cout << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you have [boost](/questions/tagged/boost)

You can just do:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
boost::split(tokens, input, boost::is_any_of("|:."));
```

(Then it's just a matter of filling the tokens into your struct)

---

[Try it yourself !](https://godbolt.org/z/F58iPY) :

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    auto input = "user1:192.168.0.1|user2:192.168.0.2|user3:192.168.0.3";

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    boost::split(tokens, input, boost::is_any_of("|:."));    

    for (auto tok : tokens) {
      std::cout << tok << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### If you don't have [boost](/questions/tagged/boost)

A `std::regex` can do the same thing:

```
std::regex re("\\.;\\|");
std::sregex_token_iterator first{input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1}, last;//the '-1' is what makes it split
std::vector<std::string> tokens{first, last};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> splitStr( const std::string &s, 
                                   const std::string &delim = " \t" )
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0, n = 0;
          ( pos = s.find_first_not_of( delim, pos ) ) != std::string::npos; 
          pos += n )
    {
        n = s.find_first_of( delim, pos );

        n = ( n == std::string::npos ? s.size() : n ) - pos;

        v.push_back( s.substr( pos, n ) );
    }

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    const std::string s( "user1:192.168.0.1|user2:192.168.0.2|user3:192.168.0.3 " );
    for ( const auto &item : splitStr( s, ":|" ) )
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
user1
192.168.0.1
user2
192.168.0.2
user3
192.168.0.3
```

That is you can use searching member functions `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of` of the class `std::string`.

You can supply any set of delimiters to the function.

Comment: This solution is too much boilerplate to be recommended - any <regex> would be simpler than this.

Comment: @darune It is a simple solution that is clear and moreover useful for beginners.

Comment: It's too much "boilerplate" the way you wrote the split function. That is not good for beginners. So I guess I just disagree.

Comment: @darune The function implementation  is very good. Using regualr expressions will arise more questions. At least it is the best suggestion among presented here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to do complicated string process. It's often easier to maintain and work with than processing it by hand.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::string s = "user1:192.168.0.1|user2:192.168.0.2|user3:192.168.0.3";
    std::regex r(R"_((user\d+)\:((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}))_");

    struct record {
        std::string username;
        std::string ip;
    };
    std::vector<record> records;
    std::transform(
        std::sregex_iterator{ s.begin(), s.end(), r }, std::sregex_iterator{},
        std::back_inserter(records),
        [](auto& sm) -> record { return { sm[1],sm[2] }; }
    );

    std::transform(
        records.begin(), records.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, "\n"},
        [](auto& rec) { return rec.username + ':' + rec.ip; }
    );
}
```